# Can Slenderman be harmed by ordinary weapons like knives and guns?

Tags: folklore, slender-man

I'm moderately familiar with the two Slenderman games on PC, in which the player can't do much besides run away and shine a flashlight at things.

So I was wondering: In the broader Slender Mythos (the "Big Five" ARGs, the original SA posts, etc), **have any characters ever tried attacking Slenderman with ordinary weapons like knives or guns?** And if so, what happened to them?

Comment: Slenderman is just an internet meme, so there's no official canon to determine whether he can be harmed by ordinary weapons or not.

Comment: @Kai I wouldn't say a meme, slendeman is no meme. But this question i fear has no answer nevertheless. Slendie is just an urban legend that can bent to every and each storyteller's will. If he requires him to be harmed with weapons it will, otherwise it won't, simple as that. We're far from formalizing the myth and setting rules to it.

Comment: How is Slenderman not a meme?  It's even known the original image where Slenderman came from - posted to the Something Awful forums by a user named Eric Knudsen in June 8, 2009.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slender_Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there is no canon for Slenderman so the general question of whether or not he can be harmed is not answerable and will be subject to the plot of whatever series it is a part of. However, to answer your question on if it has happened, the answer is **yes**.

In the [EveryManHybrid](https://www.youtube.com/user/EverymanHYBRID) episode [Ashen Waste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjjaszhmq54), [Evan](http://everymanhybrid.wikia.com/wiki/Evan) charges slenderman with a baseball bat he has picked up earlier in the video. As often happens when in close proximity to Slenderman, the video distorts and we only see the indirect result of the encounter, which is that Evan is injured, bleeding from the mouth, and the gang moves quickly to get him to the car and to a doctor.

[MarbleHornets](https://www.youtube.com/user/MarbleHornets) also has some close encounters with Slenderman with equally fruitless results. The best example I can think of is when Jay meets Slenderman in the hotel room (I do not know which entry this is, I will update with a link when I can find it). It is not clear if Jay is pulled to Slenderman or if he charges him but it causes the video to cut and Slenderman is unharmed.

[TribleTwelve](https://www.youtube.com/user/TribeTwelve) has an instance of Noah attempting to shoot Slenderman in the video [Mary Asher's Phone Call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alHDQZRV4CU), but Noah is unsuccessful in inflicting any damage.

In some of the paranormal stories threads on Something Awful, stories were posted that even had Slenderman showing up in war zones like the Gulf War or World War 2, and in those cases he was able to terrorize and/or kill even soldiers armed with military weaponry.

So in all of the examples I am aware of, Slenderman is immune to harm from weapons, but this can change if someone writes a story that contradicts it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I actually started watching Marble Hornets myself after asking this question; the hotel room encounter was in [Entry #52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jlbdYFY79M&ob). There's also Alex charging at the Slenderman in [Entry #70](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNazUSCAEBw), with a pretty similar result.